# SQL Server: generating varchar as number with some conditions

Tags: sql, join, casting, sql-update

I have a problem that my current script this correctly assigned to each reference entity.

```
update dbo.expozitura
set reference_subjektu = replicate('0', 8-len(rn) )+b.rn
from dbo.expozitura a
INNER JOIN 
(
    select dbo.expozitura.cislo_subjektu , cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by cislo_subjektu) as varchar) as  rn
    from dbo.expozitura
)b ON b.cislo_subjektu = a.cislo_subjektu

select * from dbo.expozitura;
```

OUTPUT: (Step 1)

```
cislo_subjektu  reference_subjektu  organizace  adresa_ulice    psc         ico
1               00000001                 2                                7774588
2               00000002                 0      Linkoln 50                7774588
3               00000003                 0                     403 31     729544866
4               00000004                 0                                8544569
5               00000005                 0      Linkoln 66     578 99     8542155
6               00000006                 0                     558 41     8542155
```

STEP 2:

I need to make one more statement that if there is any "dbo.expozitura" with the same "ico". So take his first reference and assign it to all the same according to the specific "ico". Such will be more.

OUTPUT:

If everything was correct, this should be the final result.

```
cislo_subjektu  reference_subjektu  organizace  adresa_ulice    psc         ico
1               00000001                 2                                7774588
2               00000001                 0      Linkoln 50                7774588
3               00000003                 0                     403 31     729544866
4               00000004                 0                                8544569
5               00000005                 0      Linkoln 66     578 99     8542155
6               00000005                 0                     558 41     8542155
```

Please help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an updateable common table expression to achieve this:

```
With x as (
    Select
        reference_subjektu,
        min(reference_subjektu) over (partition by ico) nval
    from
        expozitura
) update
    x
set
    reference_subjektu = nval
where
    reference_subjektu != nval;
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b44b0/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Have you any next idea how can i fix it?

Comment: Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__expozitu__780A73EA03B2F7CC'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.expozitura'. The duplicate key value is (00000001).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @RadekTarant If your table has a unique constraint on the reference_subjektu column, then your question is impossible.

Comment: yeah sry, my column is unique in my test but normal is not unique. Sry i changed and try again your script. :)